# Why CGContext is not drawing in a loop?

Tags: ios, animation, drawing, cgcontext

I am using EFCircularSlider to display a circular line and user will move handler as follow:

[image]

I have completed all user requirements except displaying red line in animation behaviour. I can't change my code much. I am trying to draw this arc line gradually. Instead of using animation I am using to use CGContext and display the circle in the loop. But it is drawing the image at the end of the loop. I have trace it down and made sure loop is getting called properly as follow:

I'm calling the method:

```
    int tmp = self.angleFromNorth;
    while (tmp<360) {
        NSLog(@"tmp ==  %d",tmp);
        tmp+=10;
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 0.1];
        [EFCircularTrig drawUnfilledArcInContext:ctx
                                          center:self.centerPoint
                                          radius:self.radius
                                       lineWidth:self.lineWidth
                              fromAngleFromNorth:self.angleFromNorth
                                toAngleFromNorth:tmp];
           [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
```

And then it will print the line properly but only after loop is finished. When print out all the values it will display the line. But I want to make it similar to animation.

```
+(void) drawUnfilledArcInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
                          center:(CGPoint)center
                          radius:(CGFloat)radius
                       lineWidth:(CGFloat)lineWidth
              fromAngleFromNorth:(CGFloat)fromAngleFromNorth
                toAngleFromNorth:(CGFloat)toAngleFromNorth
{

    float cartesianFromAngle = CompassToCartesian(ToRad(fromAngleFromNorth));
    float cartesianToAngle   = CompassToCartesian(ToRad(toAngleFromNorth));

    CGContextAddArc(ctx,
                    center.x,   // arc start point x
                    center.y,   // arc start point y
                    radius,     // arc radius from center
                    cartesianFromAngle, cartesianToAngle,
                    0); // iOS flips the y coordinate so anti-clockwise (specified here by 0) becomes clockwise (desired)!

    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, lineWidth);
    CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapButt);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, CGSizeMake(0,0), 1, [UIColor colorWithRed:(0/255.0) green:(173/255.0) blue:(238/255.0) alpha:1.0].CGColor);
    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathStroke);

    NSLog(@"HERE");   
}
```

Output:

```
2016-09-06 22:52:48.950 EFCircularSlider[38301:288182] tmp ==  22
2016-09-06 22:52:49.056 EFCircularSlider[38301:288182] HERE
2016-09-06 22:52:49.056 EFCircularSlider[38301:288182] tmp ==  32
2016-09-06 22:52:49.161 EFCircularSlider[38301:288182] HERE
2016-09-06 22:52:49.162 EFCircularSlider[38301:288182] tmp ==  42
2016-09-06 22:52:49.265 EFCircularSlider[38301:288182] HERE
2016-09-06 22:52:49.266 EFCircularSlider[38301:288182] tmp ==  52
2016-09-06 22:52:49.371 EFCircularSlider[38301:288182] HERE
2016-09-06 22:52:49.372 EFCircularSlider[38301:288182] tmp ==  62
2016-09-06 22:52:49.475 EFCircularSlider[38301:288182] HERE
2016-09-06 22:52:49.475 EFCircularSlider[38301:288182] tmp ==  72
2016-09-06 22:52:49.580 EFCircularSlider[38301:288182] HERE
```

But the drawing will be appear once the loop is completed. I want to make it appear gradually. I appreciate if anyone can add their exprience here.

I also added:

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the event loop (after `drawRect` has returned), everything in the context will be composed to the screen. Until the end of the event loop, you're just modifying the context, not the screen. All `setNeedsDisplay` does is say "next time the event loop runs, this view needs to be drawn again." It doesn't actually draw anything itself.

Your approach cannot work. If you're calling `sleepForTimeInterval:` on the main thread (or generally any thread), you're absolutely approaching the problem incorrectly. On iOS, if you do this too long, the OS will kill your app.

You need to animate your path. This is generally best done by animating a `CAShapeLayer` (the `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd` properties can be animated). You will want to create a path rather than hand-drawing the arc. There are many introductions to this kind of animation, for example see Ole Begemann's [Animating the Drawing of a CGPath with CAShapeLayer](https://oleb.net/blog/2010/12/animating-drawing-of-cgpath-with-cashapelayer/).

The short version, though, is that you should convert your draw statements into calls on a `UIBezierPath` or `CGPath` to draw the entire arc, and then use `CABasicAnimation` to animate it.